# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find ServiceProvider with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a problem with the creation of an object. The New-function ist working, but when i pass the object to the Create, the following error is thrown.
I want to add a Service when a ServiceProvider exists. Every User can create one ServiceProvider for himself. A ServiceProvider could have a few services.
I've also set the foreign-keys for the services-table in a MIgration-file via
"add_foreign_key :services, :service_provider"
I don't have an idea why the service_provider_id isn't transfered.

Error Output

```
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ServicesController#create
    Couldn't find ServiceProvider with 'id'=
    Extracted source (around line #55):

      private
        def current_service_provider
Line 55:          @current_service_provider = ServiceProvider.find(params[:id])
      end


Parameters:        
{"utf8"=>"✓",
         "authenticity_token"=>"Z4s/ZzbbMmcXA1jAyFnEZZ/8RhS2ZO/UdI6xN5QkKQwXmJJOOo/PVsSdOUcuJvVpFJdaUi/rMtNJq5sAEdz89g==",
         "service"=>{"name"=>"dsfg", "address"=>"asdf", "radius"=>"64655", "price"=>"45", "descr"=>"sdfagasrfsdgh"},
         "commit"=>"Speichern"}
```

Models

```
class ServiceProvider < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :services

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :street, presence: true
  validates :plz, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

end
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service_provider
  has_many :service_photos

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
end
```

ServicesController

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_service, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @service = current_user.services
  end

  def show
    @service_photos = @service.service_photos
  end

  def new
    @service = Service.new
  end

  def create
    @service = current_service_provider.services.build(service_params)
    if @service.save
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each do |image|
          service.service_photos.create(image: image)
        end
      end
      @service_photos = @service.service_photos
      redirect_to edit_service_path(@service), notice: "Gespeichert"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  private
    def current_service_provider
      @current_service_provider = ServiceProvider.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_service
      @service = Service.find(params[:id])
    end

    def service_params
      params.require(:service).permit(:name, :address, :radius, :price, :descr)
    end
end
```

Form

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Erstelle deinen Service
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_for @service, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Service Name</label>
              <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Servicename", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Adresse</label>
              <%= f.text_field :address, placeholder: "Adresse", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Radius</label>
              <%= f.text_field :radius, placeholder: "Radius", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Preis</label>
              <%= f.text_field :price, placeholder: "Preis", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>Beschreibung</label>
              <%= f.text_area :descr, rows: 5, placeholder: "Beschreibung", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="rows">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div-form-group>
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg"></i>Fotos hochladen
                  <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
                </span>
              </div-form-group>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="photos"><%= render 'service_photos/list' %></div>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Speichern", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: Have added the form

Answer (score 1):

In "create" action you try to find non-existing object. You can find object by 'id' after save that. 
In your case params[:id] is not exist when "current_service_provider" method is calling.

Comment: I have to explain that first the service provider is created via web form. After that a service is created. So the service provider should be able to find via ServiceProvider.find(params[:id]).